# Portable class library for referred nuget packages dll not generated

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I created a .net standard 1.3 PCL and referred newtonsoft.json package in that library using visual studio 2015.

After that i tried referring this dll to a console application of .net framework 4.5.2 , in the console application on execution,  i get an error as

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

I see that in PCL on building project i am not getting the dlls of dependent package , why does that problem exist?
How to fix this?

Note -
build location for console application and PCL library is same.

Comment: You should not try to create any .NET Standard things in VS2015. Use VS2017 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way i found on exploration is to create nuget package using dotnet pack and refer it in project